# Importing csv file to datatable returns no results

Tags: .net, sql, datatable, oledb

This method does not throw an exception, neither does it return the rows from the csv file it reads into the DataTable. I am at a loss for what I am doing incorrectly.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
public string ImportCsvFile(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        //string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" + file.DirectoryName + "\" Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';";
        string connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};" + @" Extended Properties={1}", file.DirectoryName, "'Text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited'");
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", file.Name), con);
            // Using a DataTable to process the data
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                ds = new DataTable("MyTable");
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                adp.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Rows)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(row.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                String errorString;
                errorString = "Error occurred while importing data from source file." + System.Environment.NewLine +
                "Error Message: " + error.Message + System.Environment.NewLine +
                "Stack Trace: " + error.StackTrace;
                return errorString;
            }                    
        }
        return "File imported to DataTable";
    }
```

Comment: Just a stab here but I don't see a con.close().

Comment: With a "using" statement you don't need a .Close() call. It will close and dispose of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, this code is fine. It's the csv file that was the issue here. There was some type of file corruption or the file format was incompatible somehow.